# python re can't find this grouped name

Tags: python, regex, named

I try to give advice on the format of paper reference. For example, for academic dissertation, the format is:

```
author. dissertation name[D]. place where store it: organization who hold the copy, year in which the dissertation published.
```

obviously, there may be some punctuation in every items except for year. for example

```
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. United States: MIT, 2011
```

often, `place where store it` and `year` are missed, for example

```
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT
```

I want to program like this:

```
import re
reObj = re.compile(
r'.*\[D\]\.  \s*  ((?P<PLACE>[^:]*):){0,1} \s*   (?P<HOLDER>[^:]*)   (?P<YEAR>,\s*(1|2)\d{3}){0,1}',
re.VERBOSE
)

txt = '''Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT'''.split('\n')

for i in txt:
    if reObj.search(i):
        if reObj.search(i).group('PLACE')==None:
            print('missing place')

        if reObj.search(i).group('YEAR')==None:
            print('missing year')
    else:
        print('bad formation')
```

but I found that no YEAR are gotten
    for i in txt:
        print(i)
        print(reObj.search(i).group('HOLDER'))

outputs

```
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, 2011
MIT, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US, 2011
US, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT
MIT

for i in txt:
    print(i)
    print(reObj.search(i).group('YEAR'))
```

outputs

```
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, 2011
None
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US, 2011
None
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT
None
```

So, why my named group fails and how to fix it? thanks

Comment: `(?P<HOLDER>[^:]*)` should probably be `(?P<HOLDER>[^,]*)` - you want to match up to the next comma (or end of text), not up to the next colon.

Comment: @oyster  Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you may use

```
reObj = re.compile("""
    \[D\]\.  \s*            # [D]. and 0+ whitespaces
    (?:                     # An  optional alternation group
     (?P<PLACE>[^,:]*)      # Group "PLACE": 0+ chars other than , and :
       (?:                           # An optional sequence of
          : \s* (?P<HOLDER>[^,:]*)   # :, 0+ whitespaces, Group "HOLDER" (0+ non-colons and non-commas)
        )?
        (?:                          # An optional sequence of
          ,\s* (?P<YEAR>[12]\d{3})   # , + 0+ whitespaces, Group "YEAR" (1 or 2 and then three digits
        )?                       
    )?      
    $          # end of string
    """, flags=re.X)
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/RiXWl3/3) and [Python demos](http://rextester.com/RYMD61266):

```
import re
reObj = re.compile(
    r"\[D\]\.\s*(?:(?P<PLACE>[^,:]*)(?::\s*(?P<HOLDER>[^,:]*))?(?:,\s*(?P<YEAR>[12]\d{3}))?)?$",
    re.VERBOSE
)
txt = '''Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US, 2011
Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT'''.split('\n')

for i in txt:
    print('------------------------\nTESTING {}'.format(i))
    m = reObj.search(i)
    if m:
        if not m.group('PLACE'):
            print('missing place')
        else:
            print(m.group('PLACE'))

    if not m.group('YEAR'):
        print('missing year')
    else:
        print(m.group('YEAR'))
```

Output:

```
------------------------
TESTING Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, 2011
US
2011
------------------------
TESTING Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US, 2011
US
2011
------------------------
TESTING Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT
US
missing year
```

Comment: one more question, what if the HOLDER can use any character and punctuation. In other word, the HOLDER string expands till it meets YEAR, and if YEAR occurs, it must be the last item. So `Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, Dep 1, 2011` returns `MIT, Dep 1` as HOLDER, and  `Smith. The paper name. The subtitle of paper[D]. US: MIT, building 1998, 2011` returns `MIT, building 1998` as HOLDER. In both cases, 2011 are read as YEAR

Comment: I have tried use `.*` for HOLDER but obviously it is wrong. And since English is not my native language, I cannot found jargon for this behavior

Comment: @oyster See  https://regex101.com/r/RiXWl3/4. Replace `[^,:]*` with `.*?`